# Ajax call to webapi doesn't happen

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm following the [this kudvenkat tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PW2EJhk6ms&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&index=13)

I created the WebApi project and has the Get method.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
   List<Student> students;
   List<StudentVM> studentsvm = new List<StudentVM>();
   using (SchoolEntities sc = new SchoolEntities())
   {
   students= sc.Students.ToList<Student>();
   }
        foreach (Student s in students)
        {
          StudentVM svm = new StudentVM { Sid = s.Id, Sname = s.Name };
          studentsvm.Add(svm);
        }
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, studentsvm);
}
```

With URL request `http://localhost:3735/api/values` I get the data. I even have set a break point here. Hence when the above URL is refreshed, the break point hits.
Within the same project, I have created a html page and has the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (e)
     {
      var ulemp = $('#ulemp');
      $('#showemp').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                Url: 'http://localhost:3735/api/values',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    ulemp.empty();
                    ulemp.append(data.value);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("There is an Error");
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<button id="showemp" name="showbtn"> Show Employees</button>
<button id="clear" name="clearbtn">Clear</button>
<p id="ulemp"></p>
</body>
```

But I get neither any error nor any response. I had gone through many stack overflow questions related to WebApi and Ajax calling. Most of the questions haven't been resolved and the some which are resolved have small mistakes which I have verified on my part.

Currently I'm using VS2012 with jquery 1.7.1

It's really appreciating if someone could point me out to what I'm missing.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale When I executed the same project on my another computer, it worked perfectly right. I'm unsure what the problem was there in that particular instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: Hence, I mean it's solved by the way.

Comment: Good.. Because of *I'm following the this kudvenkat tutorial* line just wants to be sure to get the solution! For me he is the best person in the world in .net!

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable CorsAttribute? If not add it either globally or on the Get method

```
    [EnableCors(origins:"*",headers:"*",methods:"*")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        //method body
    }
```

Comment: As said: within the same project! How the *CORS* will be the case?

Comment: Im sorry my bad i didn't read right.If it is inside same project i think u don't need URL : http://localhost:3735/api/values , just URL : api/value which is the route to your method.

Comment: @Mycenaean I provided the completer URL here since I was to make sure that this might not create a problem.

Comment: @Raida Adn if you are watching kudvenkat you can actually see that in the code he writes api/controller but on the sliedes he provides full path :D . Btw best teacher ever